# How many times can I use "Express Interest" button?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

A few days ago I found an interested opportunity and I clicked "Express Interest". After that, this button never appears again on other jobs.

Does Stack Overflow limit the number of jobs user can use "Express Interest" for at a time? If the answer is yes, how long do I need to wait before I can use it with other jobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: There is no limit to the number of interests you express. However, the Express Interest feature is *only available on certain job listings.*

---

There is no limit to the number of jobs you can express interest to. There is also no wait time after expressing interest.

Express interest is a feature available for job listings that are managed by employers directly on Stack Overflow Talent. It is not available for job listings that the employers decided to manage on an external [Applicant Tracking System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicant_tracking_system) (ATS). The reason is that, unlike job applications, we have no good way of forwarding the interests to external ATSs.

Comment: Thank you, I get the point.